# how long does travel SE go between elections?

Tags: discussion, election

The last time an election related badge was awarded was in mid-2013:

https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/badges/85/caucus

It seems like on stackoverflow elections are held every year. With what frequency are they held at the travel SE?

Comment: I like the current moderators, I liked the previous ones as well... Let's not change...

Comment: Might even mean that we add a 4th!

Comment: @normal true, but it has the potential of doing so. Why mess up with a thing that is working good..

Comment: Relevant tag: [tag:sex] - oh wait, misread.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Moderator elections are not a periodic process like presidential elections in some countries. After the first set of elected moderators is in place, subsequent elections are on as-needed basis. Some examples:

- [TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/election) held their one and only election in February 2011, that is 4.5 years ago.
- [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/election) had their election in September 2012.

So, [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/election)'s example of no elections since April 2013 is not extreme.  Perhaps the moderator team and the SE Community Team do not see the need for additional moderators at this time.

---

That said, yesterday's deluge of fake-diploma spam (about 30 posts) suggests that adding another moderator could be useful. To my understanding of SE spam-blocking system, the attack would  end sooner (with the originating IP addresses blocked) if a moderator was on the scene, destroying user accounts. The spam posts were flag-deleted by community members, but only moderators can destroy accounts — and that did not happen until a [Community Manager arrived](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/591?m=23806387#23806387).

Comment: Actually, this is slightly incorrect. If you see spam, try rallying up the community to flag it as such. One of you guys raise a custom flag to let the moderators know. Having another moderator will nearly be useless, especially if none of them are awake. Generally, the network moderators jump between sites and if you see anyone with a blue name in a chatroom, ping them and let them know of the spam. In most cases, the spam is localized, and contains the same content, and we can ask the community team to place an appropriate spam block (moderators can't put blocks anyway). Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 5):

You can always check the `/election` page for each site.

For Travel, see: https://travel.stackexchange.com/election. There we notice that there have been two elections so far, ending in April 2013 and March 2016.